# c++ Finite State Machine

Tags: c++, state-machine

I've been given a homework assignment that I can't seem to wrap my head around. Our teacher wants us to program a finite state machine. Here is the code

```
#ifndefine  
#define FINITE_STATE_MACHINE_H
#include <iosfwd>

class FiniteStateMachine
    {
        Private:
        friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &, FiniteStateMachine const &);

        public:
            FiniteStateMachine(){}
            virtual FiniteStateMachine *changeState() const = 0;
            virtual char const *toString() const = 0;
            virtual ~FiniteStateMachine(){}
    };

class ON : public FiniteStateMachine
    {
        private:

        public:
            ON(){}
            FiniteStateMachine *changeState() const;
            char const *toString() const;
    };

class OFF : public FiniteStateMachine
    {
        private:        

        public:
            OFF(){ }
            FiniteStateMachine *changeState() const;
            char const *toString() const;
    };

#endif
```

The instructions are to create a FiniteStateMachine.cpp file that contains all the pertinent member functions such that the state of OFF transitions to the state of ON and vice versa.

I have attempted to write the changeState() function to return a new instance of the opposite state, but it doesn't seem to want to work and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I was trying to instantiate and return a new ON object with the following in the FiniteStateMachine.cpp

```
    FiniteStateMachine *OFF::changeState() const
        {
            FiniteStateMachine *on = new ON;
            return *on;
        }
```

and the compiler was returning the following error
    cannot convert 'FiniteStateMachine' to 'FiniteStateMachine*' in return

A classmate suggested putting it into the constructor instead of simply calling changeState()

```
OFF::OFF()
    {


        FiniteStateMachine *OFF::changeState() const
            {
                FiniteStateMachine *on = new ON;
                return *on;
            }

    }
```

the compiler returns the error
        qualified-id in declaration before '(' token

indicating it's in between changeState and the ()'s

after more keyboard banging it seems I needed to write

```
FiniteStateMachine *OFF::changeState() const
    {
        return new OFF();
    }
```

Comment: I can't see any code here, only your declarations. Have you tried anything yourself? We are not "do my homework" platform...

Comment: Show us what you tried, and what error messages you received. "It doesn't seem to work" isn't a helpful description of what is wrong

Comment: I have added the code for the changeState() function I was trying yesterday and the code suggested by a classmate for the OFF constructor this morning.

Answer (score -1):

Try to look up 'state pattern'. eg https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

This design pattern is made to solve what you ask for.

Comment: Could you provide example code how this might be of any use?

Comment: Look under 'Code Examples' at the linked page. There is an example which pretty much imlpements what he asks for.